# Alias for dom elements in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ecmascript-6

If I use e.g. a `HTMLImageElement` I just reference it like this:

```js
let image: HTMLImageElement;
...
```

In Dart it's possible to import the dom like this: `import 'dart:html' as dom;`

dom is an alias for the "dart:html" package.

In TS, the equivalent would be something like `import { main as abc } from './app';` 
'abc' is the alias for 'main'

So far so good - but I could not find a way to 'alias' the dom in TypeScript.
I'm looking for something like

```js
let image: dom.HTMLImageElement;
...
```

Is there a way to reach this goal in TS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `window` is the global element - so this should work:

```
let image: window.HTMLImageElement;
```

Or:

```
let dom = window;
let image: dom.HTMLImageElement;
```